# Acessar variável contida num BPL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Possuo um sistema desenvolvido no DelphiXE3 e estou começando a deixá-lo modular. No entanto surgiu outra dúvida. Em uma Unit que ficará em um dos módulos, possuo:

```pascal
type 
   TUsuario = record
     id:Integer;
     idEmpresa:Integer;
     usuario:string;
     foto:string;
     validade: TDateTime;
     senha:string;
     nome:string;
     admin:Boolean;
     ultimoAcesso:TDateTime;
     dataCadastro:TDateTime;
   end;
```

e

```pascal
var
  usuario:TUsuario;
```

Que em determinados momentos vou alimentar essa variável e em outros vou recuperar as informações dela. Minha dúvida: Como fazer isso?

## Atualizando

---

Meu sistema esta distribuído da seguinte maneira:

`Aplicação
 - Menu
 - Login
 - Package Default (Runtime Package)
    * Unit TUsuario
    * Unit FuncoesDefault
    * Unit FuncoesSeguranca
 - Package Cadastros (Carregado via LoadPackage)
    * CD001 - Uma tela de cadastros qualquer`

Referente ao erro de **Access Violation**, estou criando a variável dentro do package *Default*, na Unit *FuncoesDefault*.

Na minha aplicação, na tela de login, instancio a variável já criada:

```pascal
usuario:= TUsuario.Create;
```

No Evento `FormShow` do formulário CD001, chamo uma **function** da Unit *FuncoesSeguranca*, responsavel por verificar no banco de dados os direitos do usuario (inserir, editar, remover, etc). Essa **function** recebe por parâmetro uma string com o código da tela e minha variável `usuario`, criada anteriormente na tela de login.

Logo na primeira linha da minha **function** há um `if usuario.isAdmin` para verificar se o usuário é administrador. Nesse momento já recebo o erro de **Access Violation**.

## Atualizando

---

Segue um trecho da minha Unit FuncoesDefault

```pascal
unit FuncoesDefault;

interface

uses
  U_TUsuario;

var
  usuario:TUsuario;

implementation

initialization
  usuario := TUsuario.Create;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

Antes de mais nada, recomendo que você abandone a prática de usar `record` e passe a usar `class`, que é uma construção de linguagem mais moderna e muito mais poderosa. Para tal, estude um pouco sobre programação orientada a objetos, classes, `constructor`, `destructor`, métodos e propriedades.

Com relação que você perguntou, uma vez que a classe `TUsuario` esteja declarada, declare uma classe utilitária para operar sobre esses objetos, por exemplo `TUsuarioRepositorio`, que terá uma série de métodos para recuperar e salvar instâncias de `TUsuario`. Algo como:

```
type
  TUsuarioRepositorio
  public
    class function UsuarioPorNome(const aNome: string): TUsuario;
    class procedure Salvar(aUsuario: TUsuario);
  end;
```

assim, em uma certa parte do seu código você criaria um usuário assim:

```
var
  novoUsuario: TUsuario;
begin
  ...
  novoUsuario := TUsuario.Create;
  novoUsuario.Nome := 'Huguinho';
  novoUsuario.Senha := 'M@rgar1da';
  novoUsuario.Admin := True;

  TUsuarioRepositorio.Salvar(novoUsuario);
  ...
end;
```

Neste código um objeto da classe `TUsuario` é instanciado, algumas de suas propriedades são inicializadas e ele é salvo em algum lugar (arquivo ou banco de dados). Depois, para recuperar este mesmo usuário o código poderia ser:

```
var
  usuarioProcurado: TUsuario;
  nome: string;
begin
  ...
  nome := 'Huguinho';
  usuarioProcurado := TUsuarioRepositorio.UsuarioPorNome(nome);
  if usuarioProcurado <> nil then
    ShowMessage(Format('O usuário %s tem o Id=%d', [usuarioProcurado.Nome, usuarioProcurado.Id]))
  else
    ShowMessage('Nenhum usuário existe com o nome='+nome); 
  ...
end;
```

Com este modelo de trabalho você separou o objeto do código que manipula a persistência desse objeto, o que é uma ótima prática de programação e de *design*, além de permitir um alto nível de modularização de código, pois você poderá colocar os objetos em um `package` e os repositórios em outro.

Como a ideia é modularizar você pode colocar a *unit* que declara `TUsuario` (por exemplo, `Usuarios.pas`) em um *package* separado. Quando compilado, o projeto deste *package* vai gerar um arquivo **.BPL** (por exemplo, `SegurancaD17.BPL`) e um arquivo **.DCP** (`SegurancaD17.DCP`). O projeto deste *package* deve ser configurado para ser um **runtime package** e o projeto da tua aplicação deverá indicar ao menos este como um **runtime package**.

Na tua aplicação bastará fazer o `uses` da *unit* `Usuarios`. Ao compilar o teu projeto o Delphi perceberá que a *unit* está em um **runtime package** e vai gerar a dependência para ele ao invés de incluir no **.EXE**. Quando você distribuir o **.EXE**, deverá distribuir junto o `SegurancaD17.BPL`, o arquivo **.DCP** é importante para o compilador, não para o executável.

Comment: Legal, já trabalho com programação OO em java, no Delphi não deve ser muito diferente. 
Supondo então que eu tenha minha aplicação apenas o Menu, as demais telas estão separadas em BPLs. Tenho um módulo chamado segurança, que possui a tela de login. Durante o carregamento do menu, chamo a tela de login. Se validar o login, instancio um Objeto do tipo TUsuario e continuo o carregamento da aplicação.

Comment: Minha dúvida, a classe TUsuario deverá ficar em uma Unit dentro da BPL 'segurança'? Se, em algum momento eu precisar acessar esse objeto de outro módulo, como devo fazer já que ele não está no mesmo módulo que estou trabalhando, mas sim em outro?

Comment: @ThiagoThaison: adicionei alguns detalhes na minha resposta original

Comment: Criei a classe TUsuario e a incluí num package que já está no **runtime package** da minha aplicação, conforme vc sugeriu. Meu projeto está assim, por enquanto:

Aplicação
-Package Default (Runtime)
-Package Cadastro (Carregado via LoadPackage)

Dentro da minha aplicação, após o login, estou criando um objeto do tipo TUsuario (cuja declaração está dentro de um Unit, no pkg Default). Ao tentar acessar as propriedades desse objeto de dentro da pkg Cadastro, estou recebendo um erro de Access Violation, como se meu objeto não tivesse sido criado. Mas ele já está criado :(

Comment: @ThiagoThaison: se você não teve erros de compilação, assumo que a parte de *packages* esteja correta. A instanciação está ocorrendo dentro da aplicação ou dentro de um dos *packages*? É certeza que você esteja acessando a variável correta? Edite a sua pergunta para incluir os códigos onde você instancia o objeto e onde tenta acessá-lo, para ficar mais fácil de avaliar o caso.

Comment: já adicionei os detalhes na minha pergunta, como você pediu.

Comment: @ThiagoThaison: obrigado pelos detalhes. Considerando o que você mostrou, só posso entender que a variável passada para a tua função de avaliação de direitos não é a mesma que recebeu a instância de `TUsuario`. Você que a variável é instanciada no form de login, mas a variável está declarada onde? Parece ser uma variável global, é isso mesmo? Um teste simples para saber se a instância está criada e é válida é avaliar o valor da propriedade `ClassName` (no teu caso, o valor de `usuario.ClassName`. Esta propriedade deverá retornar um string contendo, no teu caso, *<nome da unit>*`.TUsuario`.

Comment: Isso mesmo @AlexSC, é uma variável global criada na minha Unit FuncoesDefault. Tentei dar um `ShowMessage(usuario.ClassName)` e recebi outro **Access Violation**. Procurei em todo meu projeto por outra possível variável `usuario` mas não encontrei, há apenas essa.

Comment: fiz uma alteração e o erro de **Access Violation** parou de acontecer. Na minha Unit FuncoesDefault, onde eu crio minha variável `usuario:TUsuario`, estou instanciando ela na seção `Initialization`, da seguinte maneira: `usuario := TUsuario.Create`. Com isso não deu mais o erro, no entanto, minha variável está vindo vazia. O `ShowMessage(usuario.ClassName)` está retornando apenas `TUsuario`. Não deveria ser `FuncoesDefault.TUsuario`?

Comment: Adicionei mais alguns detalhes à minha pergunta, @AlexSC